Swap all instances of two symbols in one expression
I have an expression like
expression = a[k] b^j c^k (k j)!

I would like to swap all instances of the symbols j and k, i.e.,
output = a[j] b^k c^j (j k)!

How should I go about doing this?

you can also do it in one command z = Unique[]; expr /. j -> z /. k -> j /. z -> k which gives what you showed.

@Nasser's comment effects the replacement carefully, but you can literally just do a[k] b^j c^k (k j)! /. {k -> j, j -> k}, because ReplaceAll only replaces once: it will see a k and replace it with j, and it doesn't rescan the expression to replace the changed j back to a k. You would need to do something like Nasser's suggestion if you need to scan the expression more than once.

While writing the question, I came up with the following:
swap[expr_, s1_, s2_] := Module[{res, symb},
   symb = Unique[];
   res = expr /. {s1 -> symb};
   res = res /. {s2 -> s1};
   res = res /. {symb -> s2};
   Return[res];
   ];

expression = a[k] b^j c^k (k j)!
result = swap[expression, k, j]

The output is
b^k c^j a[j] (j k)!

Let me know if you have something better.
Edit: I will put Nasser's and march's answers in the comments, which are more succinct. Nasser's version of my code is simply:
z=Unique[];expr/.{s1->z,s2->s1,z->s2}

Moreover, march noted that in most cases, it is enough to use
expr/.{s1->s2,s2->s1}

because

because ReplaceAll only replaces once: it will see a k and replace it with j, and it doesn't rescan the expression to replace the changed j back to a k.


Perhaps pedestrian, however:
f[j_, k_] := HoldForm[a[k] b^j c^k (k j)!]
f[k, j]

=>

